# Background image not displaying inside the div element

Tags: html, css

I want to insert images into the background of a div. But when I am doing an inline styling the background-image occurring. But after trying with external css file image not showing. 
I have checked the link, css external file linking everything checked.
here below are the code which i tried.

```css
.txt-op {
  background: url("assets/images/star.svg");
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <p class="main-title">ABOUT US</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="txt-op col-sm-6">

      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when iam linking the image via external css only problem occurring. but in same external file weblink was working fine.

help will be appreciable.

Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure that the path to assets is correct? Maybe it should be `/assets/images/star.svg`?

Comment: Make sure your path is correct to the image `./assets/images/star.svg` for example. And use Chrome Dev tools to see where it's actually trying to look for the image to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you encode the svg to data-url [e.g with this](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and use it without any path

```css
.txt-op {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='210' width='500'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198' style='fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;'/%3E Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.%0A%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <p class="main-title">ABOUT US</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="txt-op col-sm-6">

      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>
      <p>afjhaafa</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```